# How to make Asp.net Web Application Debug time shorter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, debugging, deployment

I have a large ASP.NET Web Application with the following properties:

- I am using the Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate IDE
- **.Net Framework 3.5**
- ASP.NET (web application)
- **NHibernate** version **2.2** is used as the ORM in this project
- Developer system : CPU dual Core 2.94GHz x64 with 6GB of Ram
- Project **ReBuild time 3 ~ 4 minutes**
- Build project after a change usually take 1 Minute

When a developer tries to surf a page in default mode it takes between **2 ~ 4 minutes** for the first page to appear and he/she can surf other pages in a reasonable time

When the developer wants to debug a page it takes  **4 ~ 7 minutes** to see the first page and so on.

So if the developer make a change in code and wants to check it in debug mode, he/she will go mad because it takes a lot of time to check a small change in the code.

Is there any solution to reduce the debug time?

I whittled down the a large project into **many small projects**. (the small ones are now debuggable in a resoanble time so most of them are good)

But 4 of projects, which are still large, have the **same issue** and nothing changes for them.  I also **deploy them in local IIS** but nothing changed.

Any suggestion would be appreciated

Thank you in advance

Comment: Two questions: (1) What do you mean by large?  About how many pages and user controls are there? (2) How many files do you have in App_Code?  Having a large number of classes to compile in App_Code will slow compile time significantly.

Comment: Unit testing could help.

Comment: @Mark by large I mean that the **.cproj** file is 19000 lines!!! the **aspx** pages are around than 500 pages and all of them have at least one equevalent ascx **Module** and two .resx **resource file**. the project inn fact is an **ERP** and its app_code contains 50 **.cs** file

Comment: @DarinDimitrov How Unit Testing can help me? can you gimme an example?

Comment: I am not familiar enough with the design of your application so I cannot give you an example, but the idea is to unit test the different parts of your application in isolation so that when a developer needs to know whether the code he wrote works he doesn't need to run the entire application and go through 10 pages before reaching the one that he is currently working on but simply run the unit tests that he wrote before implementing the functionality: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing

Comment: Do you know how much of the initialization time is compilation vs. loading of resources (i.e. caching data & resources from external sources)? In other words, if you set a breakpoint in the global asax application start event handler, how long does it take to hit it?  If you place another breakpoint immediately before your custom site initialization code, how long does that take?  Basically, we need data about what part of the AppDomain startup & requested page/control compilation is taking the longest.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I'm affraid **Unit Testing** cannot help me in this case cause I'm working in UI not in service or logic. **@Mark** I'm gathering information you need

Comment: When working on the UI, you normally don't need to restart your application everytime you make a change in the markup. All you have to do is hit F5 in the browser to see the change immediately without even recompiling the web application. If you modify the code behind and need a recompile, then comes the unit test part. Unfortunately if the application is poorly designed and you have strong coupling between the different layers it is difficult to apply those concepts.

Comment: Have you tried profiling the application to see what is happening in that startup time?  We had a similar type of application that was taking 1-2 minutes to startup on developer machines, and discovered that our (mis)use of LINQ-to-SQL was the culprit, because our startup pages were making 100's of queries to the database for initial load and populating the page.  Sometimes though, just by the sheer scale of a project it will take a certain amount of time to compile and build everything.  In that case, there's not much you can do except get faster build machines or make smaller projects.

Comment: Also, for very large projects I have found getting a solid state drive to help significantly, especially for development machines that are running the database engine locally.  This of course doesn't address the underlying issue of an unmanageably-large project, but it may help reduce your build time somewhat for a relatively small cost ($100-$150).

Comment: For testing very small changes, you could try checking Enable Edit and Continue under Web > Debuggers in the web project properties.

Comment: Do you have CodeAnalysis enabled for the local Debug Environment?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using NHibernate as the ORM the only thing i could possibly think it takes so long is because you are misusing it, resulting in SELECT N+1 problem or similar.

On the other side i don't know you're solution structure but i suggest you take a look here:
http://geekswithblogs.net/MarkPearl/archive/2012/05/24/vs2010-large-solution-bottle-neck.aspx

Answer (score 0):

An useful thing in large web projects is a wise use of unit testing (microsoft or nunit for instance) in order to test the business objects and logic, db connections and so on. The unit tests can be debugged in a quicker fashion since  the development webserver and webforms overhead is not necessary in this scenario. Working on this way the main slow debugger will be used only for very specific web UI issues.